# Mload error While execution

Tags: database, teradata

When executing the below script for MLOAD m getting the below error in the                      putty :

```
    output:
    $ ./multiload.sh
    ./multiload.sh: .LOGTABLE:  not found.
    ./multiload.sh[2]: .logon:  not found.
    ./multiload.sh[4]: .begin:  not found.
    ./multiload.sh[5]: .layout:  not found.
    ./multiload.sh[6]: 0403-057 Syntax error at line 6 : `(' is not expected.
```

**======= Script Starts Here===============**

```
    Multiload.sh:

    .logtable ETLT5.INFA_SOURCE12_LOG
    .logon ttdbia/a0c9sx,blue@126;
   drop error,Work Tables
    .begin import mload tables ETLT5.INFA_SOURCE12 SESSIONS 20;
    .layout InputFile_layout;
     .field col1
    .dml label Table_InsertDML;
    .insert into ETLT5.INFA_SOURCE12
```

values

```
    .import infile /nas/infred/data/SrcFiles/fastload.txt
     format vartext  ','
     display errors
     layout InputFile_Layout
     apply Table_InsertDML;
    .end mload;
     .logoff;
```

I cannot find any useful link present on the internet ,for fastload there were too many but Mload has very less. Please help me in this .Thanks in Advance :)

Have tried the script from the provided links:

> http://forgetcode.com/Teradata/1945-MULTILOAD-Example

Answer (score 1):

Each MLoad command must be preceded by a period and must end with a semicolon.

Each Teradata SQL command must end with a semicolon (and must be valid SQL).

```
.logtable ETLT5.INFA_SOURCE12_LOG -- missing semicolon
.logon ttdbia/a0c9sx,blue@126;
drop error,Work Tables  -- that's not valid SQL
.begin import mload tables ETLT5.INFA_SOURCE12 SESSIONS 20;
.layout InputFile_layout;
 .field col1 -- missing semicolon
.dml label Table_InsertDML;
.insert into ETLT5.INFA_SOURCE12 -- no period

 values -- which values?

.import infile /nas/infred/data/SrcFiles/fastload.txt
 format vartext  ','
 display errors
 layout InputFile_Layout
 apply Table_InsertDML;
.end mload;
 .logoff;
```

Why don't you look at the official Teradata docu?

[MLoad Examples](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/Load_and_Unload_Utilities/B035_2409_035K/2409apD.032.1.html)